# Linking Java program against uber jar

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, jar

I've got a Java library which handles REST interactions for various services that I work on.  This project produces an uber jar which uses maven relocation to put some widely used libraries into separate namespaces to not cause overlap problems with the services using it.  I would like to build against this uber jar, the one ending in **all**, however when I reference it from my other projects it only ever pulls in the non-uber jar.

My Maven Local Repo looks like this:

```
_remote.repositories
rest-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT-development-all-sources.jar
rest-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT-development-all.jar
rest-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
rest-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
rest-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
rest-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
maven-metadata-local.xml
```

I've tried importing 1.0-SNAPSHOT, 1.0-SNAPSHOT-development, 1.0-SNAPSHOT-development-all.  But first one only imports the non-uber jar, the rest are not found.  What do I need to do to link against the **all** jar?

Also using **provided** does not work here because I'm using this in a spark environment where older versions of this library must be used causing conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number

So you can do that by adding the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>your-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>development-all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly what I needed.